How to compress video but also preserve audio track names?
I have a series of MP4 files that I intend to compress into x265. The files have two audio tracks, to which a name and language is set.
I want the files compressed the video but keeping the audio tracks intact, including the name.
My current script compresses and preserves the languages, but loses the audio track names.
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion


set FFmpegPath=ffmpeg.exe

:: Loop through all MP4 files in the current folder
for %%F in (*.mp4) do (
    echo list file: %%F
    echo make on: %%F

    :: Run ffmpeg for each MP4 file, converting to x265 with quality 19 and preserving all metadata, including track names (which it does not do)
    "%FFmpegPath%" -i "%%F" -c:v libx265 -crf 19 -c:a copy -map 0 -map_metadata 0 -map_chapters 0 "%%~dpF%%~nF_x265.mp4"

    echo Made %%F
)

pause


Add -report and rerun. Share report.

Here: https://www.swisstransfer.com/d/1f879f5d-4b6b-49f1-9129-880348e131e0

Only need the report of one command, not the entire folder.

That is the file generated just by running the command on the first file
